# Nginx - Symfony app - redirect HTTP p to HTTPS

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm working on a Symfony application running on an Nginx server.

I'd like to automatically redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Here's a snippet from my nginx.conf file:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name xxxxxx;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        root /home/site/wwwroot/public;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name  xxxxx; 

        location / {            
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
    
        # Disable .git directory
        location ~ /\.git {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
        location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
            fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
            fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }
    
        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
    }
```

The website is accessible via HTTPS, but I get a timeout error when using HTTP.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

I analyzed the network traffic for an HTTP request on Wireshark, I think the server is not responding in HTTP:

[Wireshark analyze :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJKA4.png)

```
    TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 61814 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 
    MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM

    TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 61814 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 
    MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
    
    ....
```

Comment: You use `8080` for both http and https? Is that even possible? If it is you aren't checking if the incoming request is already https before redirecting

Comment: How to find the port used for HTTP? I tried the default port 80 for HTTP, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I didn't find any explicit declarations in the Nginx configuration.

Comment: if you're using a non-standard port for HTTPS (the standard one is 443) you need to include the port in the URL e.g. the url would be https://example.com:8080 if that is where you intend to serve https requests from